# Do .htc style behaviours still work if javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-components

Do .htc style behaviours still work if javascript is disabled?

I'd like to use whatever:hover to create some css only drodpowns and would like to know if IE will still pay attention to the htc file if js is disabled.

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Now I feel stupid. I have now and disabling javascript in IE6 definitely breaks the whatever:hover and pngfix behaviours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a word, no.

In two words, in order to satisfy the SO reply box, “no” and “no” (again).